# How do you disable Ambient mode?

Tags: google

I disabled Google Assistant on my phone* but Google's Ambient mode kept showing up when my phone was on charge.

I didn't want Ambient mode (it wasted power and blocked me from accessing the lock screen); how do I make it go back to pre-Assistant behaviour?

Note: I *have* turned off Google Assistant; this had no effect.

- Mi2S with Mokee kernel (Android 8.1.0)

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully disabled Ambient mode.

... by turning *on* Google Assistant and then turning *off* all the options (including Ambient mode).

The Google Assistant options can be reached (on my phone at least) by traversing: Settings | Google | Account Services | Search, Assistant & Voice | Google Assistant | Assistant (tab) | Assistant Devices | {choose your device}.

I'd like to see Assistant **off** -> Ambient **off**, but for now it's a solution...